# To check sum of two function is meromorphic or not

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

$\phi(z) = Re(z) + f(z)
$

where $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function. then WOTF is true,

1)$\phi $ is meromorphic

2)$\phi $ and $  f(z) $ has same number of singularities

3)$\phi $ is analytics in every closed and bounded region provided it has no poles

4)$\phi $ has no singularities

if i take $ f(z) =-z/2$ which is analytics and hence meromorphic then $Re(z) + f(z) = x + f(z)$ = $ (z+ \bar z)/2 -z/2 $ = $\bar z /2$ which is not analytics hence no point in talking about singularities. but none the option matches.

Comment: You are right. None of the options is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your time.